# Vertical line in a Matlab plot not showing up: problem with scaling

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add a vertical line to a plot in Matlab but it does not show up. I think the issue is the scaling of the numbers I'm considering, that is too small. This is my code:

**CASE 1: The line does not show up**

```
A=randn(1000,1)*10^(-15);

[f,x]=ksdensity(A);
plot(x,f, ':k') 
hold on
line([0 0],[0 10^(-14)])
hold off
```

**CASE 2: The line shows up**

```
A=randn(1000,1);

[f,x]=ksdensity(A);
plot(x,f, ':k') 
hold on
line([0 0],[0 1])
hold off
```

How can I make the line showing up in case 1?

Comment: What release are you working with?

Comment: I am using R2017b

Comment: The line is just too small to see, I would guess. Why do you want to draw such a short line? — I mean small w.r.t. the axis scaling. The y-axis if your distribution is not scaled when you scale the sample values, only the x-axis is.

Comment: The height doesn't matter. It should just be centered at zero. I don't understand why it does not show up.

Comment: Try using `line([0 0],[0 1])` in case 1, you’ll see the line showing up there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line shows up in both cases.  In **Case 2**, evaluate

```
ylim([0 10.1^(-14)])   % sets range of y axis to be [0 10.1^(-14)]
```

which will simply zoom in and reveal that very very very tiny line was plotted all along.  Just not visible when y-range was [0, 0.45].

This confirms @CrisLuengo's comment.

---

*Response the OP's comment*:
If you want to make them **both** show up, I suggest something like the following:

```
A=randn(1000,1);
[f,x]=ksdensity(A);
plot(x,f, ':k') 
hold on
line([0 0],[0 1])
hold off
ylim([0 max(f)])    % <--- sets the y-axis limits based on output from ksdensity
```

Comment: Thanks. If I add your code to mine, now is the other plot that does not show up. Is there a way to make them BOTH showing up?

Comment: Sigh. @user3285148: you need to make your line longer, then you’ll be able to see it on that plot. Think about why you are making the line this short, what your expectations are for the scale of the y-axis in the plot, and what the *actual* scaling there is, then try to understand why your expectations don’t match reality. This is not complicated.